# Is there a simpler function $f$ equivalent to $f(x)=af(x-1)^2+bf(x-1)+c$?

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, quadratics, functional-equations

I have been using the function $$f(x)=af(x-1)^2+bf(x-1)+c$$ for a project, but wanted to know if there was a closed form of the equation or a form of the function in relation to $f(0)$ or $f(1)$. If not, is there a way to solve for a, b, and c with 3 or 4 values of $f(x)$? I know that $$f(1)=af(0)^2+bf(0)+c$$ $$f(2)=a^3f(0)^4+2a^2bf(0)^3+2a^2cf(0)^2+ab^2f(0)^2+2abcf(0)+ac^2+abf(0)^2+b^2f(0)+bc+c$$
and so on, but it would be much easier if there was a simpler way of evaluating this equation.

Comment: just  think that f(x) could be $sin(x), e^x, x^2 , e^{sin(x)} you  can not evaluate ist if you do not specify f

Comment: If $f(k)$ is known for $k=0,1,2,3$ then you have three linear equations $f(1)=af(0)^2+bf(0)+c$,
$f(2)=af(1)^2+bf(1)+c$,
$f(3)=af(2)^2+bf(2)+c$

from which you can solve for $a,b,c$, assuming there is a solution.

Comment: By $f(x)=(g(x)-b/2)/a$ you can convert it to $g(x)=g(x-1)^2+K$ where $K=-b^2/4+ac+b/2$. I don't think there is a closed form possible for that, maybe in few special cases ...

Comment: What you ask is an equivalent of [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map).

Comment: The [OEIS sequence A003095](https://oeis.org/A003095) is a simple example where $\,a=1,b=0,c=1\,$ with lots of references.